# PHP redirect website with only domain change

Tags: php, .htaccess

**I am asking the same question that has already been asked several times but none of them has answered so far.**

I want to redirect the website to the clone folder on the web server.

Following URL was previously in use.

http://www.websiteurl.com/vshop/index.php?page=shop.product_details&product_id=440

Now i've a new setup on the same URL but different folder.

http://www.websiteurl.com/payonline/index.php?page=shop.product_details&product_id=440

The first folder name is "vshop" and 2nd one is "payonline".

Can somebody please tell me how can i keep the complete url, but change the folder name, I don't want to use "search or replace" feature. I might need to change the complete domain.

Please do also tell me if .htaccess is better of php script will work fine. 
Thanks

Comment: Do you mean changing the **folder name** rather than the **domain**?

Comment: here I wanted to change the **folder name**, but then i decided to remove only **folder** in the **redirected url.** .
BTW. domain is same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Htaccess RewriteRule should do it for you.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^vshop/(.*) payonline/$1 [QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks.. let me try. and what if need to remove payonline folder and redirect it to main site?.

Comment: wow.. it worked. thank you.. I just remvoed vshop and payonline 

 `RewriteEngine On'
 RewriteRult ^/(.*) /$1 [QSA] `

but it keeps **vshop** on url

Comment: Glad it worked for you and helped you solve your problem(s) `:D`